# Probability on spreading of rumors between $n+1$ people

Tags: probability

Exercise 21, Ch. 2 from [Feller's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471257087)

> In a town a n+1 inhabitants, a person tells a rumor to a second person, who in turn repeats it to a third person, etc. At each step, the recipient of the rumor is chosen at random from the n people available. Find the probability that the rumor will be told r times without: a) returning to the originator, b) being repeated to any person. Do the same problem when at each step the rumor is told by one person to a gathering of N randomly chosen people. (The first question is the special case N=1).

The question is particularly answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550628/rumors-told-between-n1-people) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12689/probability-on-spreading-of-rumors).
I solved cases where N=1, but do not understand solution with case a) for N people.
The solution is 
$\displaystyle P={\left(1-\frac{N}{n}\right)}^{r-1}$ but I do not understand how it is deduced.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let event $A_i,\; i=2,3,\ldots,r$ be the event that at the $i^{th}$ step the first person is excluded when $N$ people are chosen from $n$ people (the teller in each of these steps is *not* the first person).

For any step $i=2,3,\ldots,r$,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(A_i) &=& \dfrac{\text{#ways to choose $N$ people from $n-1$}}{\text{#ways to choose $N$ people from $n$}} \\
&&\\
&=& \binom{n-1}{N} \bigg/ \binom{n}{N} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{n-N}{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Then, we require:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P\left(\bigcap_{i=2}^r{A_i}\right) &=& \prod_{i=2}^r{P(A_i)} \\
&=& \left[\dfrac{n-N}{n}\right]^{r-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}