# Combinatorics and probability of rumour

Tags: probability, combinatorics, self-learning

**Spread of rumors.** In a town of **n+1** inhabitants, a person tells a rumor to a second person, who in turn repeats it to a third person and so on. At each step the recipient of the rumor is chosen at random from the **n** people available.
I want to find the probability that rumor will be told **r** times without
 A)Returning to originator and

B)without being repeated to any person.

Secondly, How to solve this question when at each step the rumor is told to gathering of **N** randomly chosen people.

Comment: Have you searched this site for rumor?  There are many questions on the subject.  Please review those and see if they answer your question, then show what you have tried and where you are stuck.  In particular [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550628/rumors-told-between-n1-people) seems very similar

Comment: possible duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12689/probability-on-spreading-of-rumors?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be the event that the rumor is told $r$ times without being told to any person who already heard it. We can say right away that $P(R|r \ge n)=0$, since there are only $n+1$ people.

Now consider this. For the first person, there are $n$ people to tell that have not yet heard it. Thus the probability of not repeating it to someone who knows it is $\frac{n}{n}=1$. For the second person, there are $n$ people to tell and $n-1$ do not know it already, so the probability for that is $\frac{n-1}{n}$. Basically we have that, after $n$ "tells", the probability is
$$\frac{n}{n}*\frac{n-1}{n}*\frac{n-2}{n}*...*\frac{n-r+1}{n}$$
which is the same as
$$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!n^r}$$
and that should be the answer.

Comment: If n=5 and r=3 the answer is 0.48 but if I use $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!n}$ answer is different why?

Comment: Whoops! The $n$ on the denominator should be raised to the *r*th power. I'll change my answer.